# Grouped Progress Bar Chart by Multiple Categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to create a grouped set of "progress" bar charts in R. I can do this in Excel, but I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for completing this task in R. Here is the graph that I am attempting to reproduce in R (not replicate exactly with the data I provide below):

[image]

As you can see, I basically am attempting to create a graph to show the fill of blue as it approaches the bounds of grey. To do this in Excel, I put one of the values on the secondary axis, something that I believe `ggplot` does not allow or play kindly with.

So far, I can create the graph without the sub group (1, 2, 3, 5) in R using this code:

```
# Stackoverflow example
size <- 5
x <- data.frame(cat = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), foo = 'test', bar = runif(size))
y <- data.frame(cat = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), foo = 'test 2', bar = runif(size))
data <- rbind(x, y)

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = data[data$foo == 'test',], aes(x = cat, y = bar, fill = foo), stat = 'identity',
           position = 'identity', width = 0.5, fill = 'grey60', color = 'grey60') +
  geom_bar(data = data[data$foo == 'test 2',], aes(x = cat, y = bar, fill = foo), stat = 'identity',
           position = 'identity', width = 0.25, fill = 'royalblue2', color = 'royalblue2') +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

However, once I add the subgroup `dog`, I cannot figure out how to graph my data by `cat` and then `dog`. I have attempted using factor and fill to create the sub-level, but with no success. I assume the answer will utilize `stat =` or `position =`, but I'm unfamiliar with all of the options for those commands and whether or not that is the best route to pursue.

```
size <- 5
x <- data.frame(cat = c('a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'd'), dog = c(1, 2, 5, 4, 5), foo = 'test', bar = runif(size))
y <- data.frame(cat = c('a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'd'), dog = c(1, 2, 5, 4, 5), foo = 'test 2', bar = runif(size))
data <- rbind(x, y)

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = data[data$foo == 'test',], aes(x = cat, y = bar, fill = factor(dog)), stat = 'identity',
           position = 'identity', width = 0.5, fill = 'grey60', color = 'grey60') +
  geom_bar(data = data[data$foo == 'test 2',], aes(x = cat, y = bar, fill = factor(dog)), stat = 'identity',
           position = 'identity', width = 0.25, fill = 'royalblue2', color = 'royalblue2') +
  coord_flip()
```

Thank you for any and all help and please, feel free to ask any questions for clarification!

Comment: What if you try something to include group = dog in your aesthetic and position = "dodge" to geom_bar?

Comment: @jonathande4, thanks for the suggestion. Ignore my previous comment because this appears to work!